# Why does more melanin means harder vitamin D production if melanocytes lie deeper in the skin than keratinocytes?

Tags: skin, pigmentation, vitamins, melanin

From my Googling, I understand that keratinocytes are primarily responsible for generating vitamin D from UV rays, and melanocytes are for producing melanin to block UV rays. However in lots of skin diagrams I've found, such as [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Shown-is-a-diagram-of-a-melanocyte-in-the-basal-layer-of-the-epidermis-transferring_fig1_340253811), melanocytes lie deeper in the skin than keratinocytes. Wouldn't it follows that no matter how much melanin you have, it shouldn't be any more difficult for you to generate vitamin D, given that keratinocytes are more superficial than melanocytes, so vitamin-D making with keratinocytes should happen before UV blocking with melanocytes?

Comment: In your googling about melanocytes have you also read what happens to melanine after it is produced in melanocytes?

Comment: @BagiM There's this sentence, "Once synthesized, melanin is contained in special organelles called melanosomes which can be *transported to nearby keratinocytes* to induce pigmentation." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanocyte#Melanogenesis). But what does that mean? Does melanin transported to keratinocytes "cover" them up, preventing them from making vitamin D or something?

Comment: Now that you noticed term melanosomes, you can google images with "melanosomes" to see how are melanosomes distributed in skin cells. Searching for "melanosomes racial" should give you some images highliting differences in melanosomes distribution between skin types. Sadly, many general skin section diagrams show melanine distribution in caucasian skin as default, so you need to be a bit more particular/persistent in your search.